# CakePHP validation messages position

Tags: validation, cakephp, message

Normally, the CakePHP's validation messages from models like:

```
class User extends AppModel {
    public $name = 'User';
    public $validate = array(
        'username' => array(
            'required' => array(
                'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
                'message' => 'A username is required'
            ),
            'regexp' => array(
                'rule' => '/^[a-z0-9]{3,10}$/i',
                'message' => 'Only letters and integers, min 3, max. 10 characters'
            )
        )
    )
}
```

Are printed below the inputs, I mean that messages: `'message' => 'A username is required'`

So it looks like:

```
|INPUT|
[Message]
```

How do I can change that so the messages gonna be added to the array:

```
$errors[] = 'Message';
```

And then, I would like to use `foreach` to print them in one place.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CakePHP has all of the validation errors available to the view in $this->validationErrors. So I loop through them thusly:

```
<?php if ( !empty($this->validationErrors['Model']) ) { ?>
<div id="errorlist">
    <h3><a href="#">You have errors in your submission. <?php echo $warnimage; ?></a></h3>
    <div>
    <ul>
    <?php foreach( $this->validationErrors['Model'] as $val ){ ?>
        <li><?php echo $val; ?></li>
    <?php } ?>
    </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

EDIT

**Where to place this code?**
Place the code in the view where you would like it displayed.

**How to disable displaying those errors below inputs?**
I don't disable that display but suppose if you wished you could just unset $this->validationErrors['Model']. (untested)

Another solution is to use elements as shown in this [article by Miles Johnson](http://milesj.me/blog/read/cakephp-list-errors).

Comment: Really? Where should I place that code ? Also, how to disable displaying those errors below inputs? I guess I'd have to create new View, right?